# How to I access a 2.5 hard drive when it tells me I don't have permissions?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, format

I took out a hard drive and replaced, and put the old drive (500 GB) into a 2.5 USB external case. I cannot seem to get in and do any formatting, petitioning, nothing. I use the disk utility, and it starts for the format, but after hours, and I mean like FIVE hours, the little indicator is still showing something, but it seems stuck. When I kill the process and reboot my machine, and TRY AGAIN, when I attempt to do anything, it tells me I do not have permission to do this! It is infuriating. I am not proficient in using the terminal, or really understanding partitions, MBRs, etc. I had wanted to reformat as FAT32 so I an use this external drive both with my Ubuntu machine or with Windows 10 as extra file storage. OR: I had also wanted to install an operating system on it and be able to boot to that. I can't seem to do either of those things until I can get the drive to actually be usable in either Win or Ubuntu machines.
Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Check if ntfs-3g and exfat-utils packages are installed & install GParted.
Open GParted, let it sacn for devices, go to Device on menu bar, select "Create Partition Table", then create "GPT". (Make sure correct device is selected from GParted Menu)

Apply the changes, go to Partition menu, select "New" and make a "NTFS" partition (it can also be used in Linux as well as windows, file size limit is more than 4GB & faster speeds), then Apply changes.
Done

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was finally able to get the darned thing reformatted and viewable in Windows and Ubuntu. I ended up using the Disk Management in Windows from my desktop machine. I had originally tried using the Windows, but the drive was not recognized in the file explorer. I then learned of the disk management tool on Win10, and for some reason, my fiddling finally won out. I am not sure I'd have been smart enough to actually follow your instructions. But a huge thanks to you for answering my question, and I appreciate it.